# how to freez `<td>` at time of scrolling a page in asp.net?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, css

How to keep the `<td>` Fixed/Frozen when the page will be scrolling vertically.

Comment: You realy need to be more verbose than this. What td? How does your code look like? What is currently the behavior? What do you want to change?

Comment: are you talking about header / footer rows? "thead"...

Answer (score 1):

Simply use CSS. `position:fixed` for that td